# Is there a way to reliably retrieve the dimensions of the largest version of a facebook album photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm querying an album's photos using the graph api explorer.

```
graph.facebook.com/[album_id]/photos
```

The result includes an "images" key which lists eight image versions. The largest is listed as `2048x1529`, however when I open the actual image it is only `604x451`, which are the dimensions listed for the next largest version.

My app needs to know accurate image dimensions ahead of time. How can I reliably find the largest available image's dimensions?

Comment: Which SDK you are using? What have you tried?

Comment: This issue is apparent using the Graph API Explorer. My code uses the ruby OAuth2 Gem.

Comment: The values are incorrect, I haven't really tried anything other than obtaining the JSON response from the graph API and observing that the values are incorrect.

Comment: If you look at https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305 from the facebook Photo Graph documentation, you see it has a field: {
width: 2048,
height: 1363,
source: "http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s2048x2048/5041_98423808305_40796308305_1960517_6704612_n.jpg"
}, where it claims the image is 2048x1363, but it is actually 604x402.  This is clearly a bug they recently introduced, when will they fix it?  Who knows?

Comment: Thanks for confirming my issue. I'm new to the Facebook API so I wasn't sure if it was a new bug or something people are familiar with and work around somehow. I actually tried filing a bug but their bug reporter would not submit.

Comment: @KrisErickson would you mind creating a bug for this? https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create The form does not work for me, but other's have said it works for them. Link it here and I'll vote for it.

Comment: There is already a bug filed: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/371607186215996

Comment: Oh, thanks. I couldn't find one :)

Answer (score 1):

Given that the results returned from ALBUM_ID/photos are not reliable, I believe the following approach is the closest you can get to your intention of getting the dimensions of the largest image version:

You can retrieve the dimensions of the enlarged image you see when you click a photo in an album online. This image is referred to as `src_big` in the `FQL` [photo table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/). You retrieve the dimensions with this `FQL` query:

```sql
SELECT src_big_width, src_big_height
FROM photo
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID
```

where OBJECT_ID is the photo's Facebook object id number.

The call looks like this,

```sql
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT src_big_width,src_big_height FROM photo WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID
```

You need

```sql
friends_photos
user_photos
```

permissions and an access token.

To get the url to the src_big image, add src_big to the query:

```sql
SELECT src_big, src_big_width, src_big_height
FROM photo
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID
```

The src_big image has a maximum width or height of 720 pixels if the image was uploaded before March 1, 2012. If it was uploaded after that date, the maximum is 960 pixels.